# I am trying to get the json response of wikipedia api but i keep getting error

Tags: json, python-3.x, request, response

I am writing basic python script for getting api response of wikipedia api using below code. i am new to python, can anyone point out my mistake please.

```
import requests
from flask import Flask

URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'
r = requests.get(URL).json()
print(r)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Haider
>   Ghufran/PycharmProjects/scrap_api/web_api.py", line 7, in 
>       r = requests.get(URL).json()   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\scrap_api\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py",
>   line 897, in json
>       return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\scrap_api\lib\json__init__.py", line
>   348, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\scrap_api\lib\json\decoder.py", line
>   337, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\scrap_api\lib\json\decoder.py", line
>   355, in raw_decode
>       raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
>   0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests
url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=info&format=json&titles=Stanford%20University'
resp = requests.get(url)
data = resp.json()

print(data)
```

This is an example of a query for the api using arguments.

Comment: how do you know (find) that link/api ...i mean where do i find api's of my desire... for example i need api of www.daraz.pk (or any other e commerce website ).... where should i looking for it ? btw thanks for your solution and for your time.

Comment: In this case i used google, and found the page for the Wikipedia API https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page And then i just used the little know how i had of the requests package.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to start consulting the API help in MediaWiki:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

By default, the results are not returned in JSON format. For example, here is call sample to Spanish Wikipedia to retrieve the sections of a page:

https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&pageid=6903884&prop=sections

and the same one in JSON (adding `format=json` to the request):

https://es.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&pageid=6903884&prop=sections&format=json